# Can a weak entity be in another relationship other than the identifying relationship with the same identifying entity type?

Tags: database

I am working on a project, Prison database .If I have a weak relationship named "visitor" identified by another entity type which is the "prisoner", Can this "visitor" be in another non-identifying relationship with the "prisoner"?